# Different behavior of cin seekg/tellg on OS X vs Linux

Tags: c++, linux, macos, iostream

I'm trying to read the entire redirected `stdin` into a `std::string` in a program I'm writing, and found that on OS X, seekg and tellg do not work as I anticipate when applied to `cin`.

Here is my minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.seekg(0, ios::end);
    if (cin.fail() || cin.bad())
        cout << "Cin seek failed." << endl;
    cout << cin.tellg() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

On Linux, when I apply this program to its own source, I get:

```
alex@linux:~$ g++ size.cpp -o size
alex@linux:~$ ./size < ./size.cpp 
225
alex@linux:~$ wc -c size.cpp
     225 size.cpp
```

On OS X, however, I get:

```
alex@osx:~$ g++ size.cpp -o size
alex@osx:~$ ./size < ./size.cpp 
-1
alex@osx:~$ wc -c size.cpp
     225 size.cpp
```

Notice that the "Cin seek failed." error message is not printed. Why is this? Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

It appears to be a problem with OS X's standard library, even though this works with clang on Linux. It works on OS X using the Homebrew G++ 4.9.

```
alex@osx:~$ g++-4.9 original.cpp -o original
alex@osx:~$ ./original < big.txt 
254167055
alex@osx:~$ g++ original.cpp -o original
alex@osx:~$ ./original < big.txt 
-1
```

**EDIT**

Here's some fast code for reading in a file to a buffer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    int read_size = ftell(stdin);

    char *buf = new char[read_size];
    rewind(stdin);
    read_size = fread(buf, 1, read_size, stdin);

    string str;
    str.append(buf, read_size); // I want to dodge this copy
                                // because speed is important

    delete [] buf;

    cout << str.length() << endl;
}
```

Here's some slow code for reading in a file to a buffer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(cin)),
                std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    cout << str.length() << endl;
}
```

Console output (big.txt is 250MB or so):

```
alex@osx:~$ time ./size < big.txt 
254167055

real    0m0.339s
user    0m0.074s
sys 0m0.264s
alex@osx:~$ time ./size-slow < big.txt 
254167055

real    1m18.180s
user    1m16.212s
sys 0m0.653s
```

Comment: I should note that I get the same results regardless of whether or not I use the "clang/gcc" commands on each system.

Comment: If you're looking to load all of `stdin` into a `std::string`, this isn't the way to do it. Just saying. That you stumbled into seeking `std::cin` is odd, but a side-note none-the-less.

Comment: Well, I'm looking to do it _fast_. I know I can do a one-liner like `(stringstream() << cin.rdbuf()).str()`. But this hides multiple reallocations and a copy. In this scenario, I expect the input data to be large.

Comment: You don't need a stringstream. an `istreambuf_iterator<>` and `std::copy` should be plenty-fast, and at least worthy of *measuring*.

Comment: I actually have measured. And it takes quite a while to copy ~250MB of data. Keeping that in only one place would be ideal.

Comment: Just for comparison. post the C-type code and method of invocation that put up that number on a 250MB file, because I cannot be the only one interested in seeing how you `fseek` on `stdin` 250MB deep. I mean it will probably work, but its just odd seeing it done with stdin ( a redirection makes it possible, it would seem). At least its good to know you can punt back to the C api.

Comment: @WhozCraig Edited with code samples.

Comment: Did you compile that fast-code on OS X ? I ask becaause `fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);` on 10.10.2 returns non-zero and `perror` reports "Illegal seek". **Edit**: it was how I'm redirecting. `prog < file` works. `cat file | prog` doesn't.

Comment: @WhozCraig -- should we move this to chat?

Comment: Nah I'm gonna hunt around on this for awhile. Its really got me intrigued. I with Dietmar were online. The guy has forgotten more about iostream programming than most people will ever know. Give it time. Experts flow out of the strangest places and times. Really bum istreambuf_iterator wasn't performant. Kinda shocked it was so poor for you. At least you can fallback to the C api though, so you got that in a pinch.

Comment: Update: it's to do with OS X's version of libc++. Compiling with G++ 4.9 Homebrew using libstd++ works just fine.

Comment: I can confirm that. I simply switch the standard C++ library choice in Xcode for the current target to libstdc++ and (after cursing for losing `std::unique_ptr<>` wtf!!) it does, in fact work correctly. Helluva find, man.

Comment: Thanks! Where should this bug be reported...?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely convinced its a bug, but I would imagine its worth bringing up to apple as a potential. I don't have their report-link, but developer.apple.com is likely a decent place to start. And by all means leave this open. An epiphany may rear if the right people see it. Wishing you the best of luck.

Comment: Apple Bug Reporter — https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/